# How do I show an HTML message with Flask if the Jinja for loop returns nothing

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask and I am looping through a table `Buyers` object in Jinja.  What I want to happen is to show a message in the HTML page if there is no data in a specific field `Buyers.supplier` of the table.

Let's say the table has 5 entries and there are no fields present, what happens in my present code is that I see my message 5 times.

Is there a way to just show the HTML message if all of the fields are empty?  Thank you!

**main.html**

```
    <div class="card-deck">
    {# Go through each blog post #}
    {% for sched in buyer_sched|sort(attribute='time') %}
        {# Only show if a supplier has been matched#}
        {% if sched.supplier.company %}
          <div class="row pl-3 ml-1">
            <p>Show some information</p>
          </div>
        {% else %}
            <p>There is no data</p>  
        {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %}
    <div />
  {% else %}
    <p>Please login and register</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I answered this in a different (perhaps not so pythonic way).

I basically iterated through the field on the python side and used a counter to count up.  If the number was greater than 0, then when I passed the integer into my html template, it wouldn't show the message.

Thank you!

```
buyer_sched = db.session.query(Buyerschedule).\
            filter(Buyerschedule.buyer_id == buyer_id).all()

        # Iterate through schedule and if all are none, set
        # completed to none
        completed = 0
        for sched in buyer_sched:
            print(f'The schedule name is: {sched.id}')
            if sched.supplier_id:
                completed = completed + 1
                print(f'completed is {completed}')
        print(f'completed is equal to {completed}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom jinja filter (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#registering-filters) to check if all are empty before the `for` loop:

```
def all_empty(data, key):
    return all(not d[key] for d in data)
app.jinja_env.filters['all_empty'] = all_empty
```

Once registered, you can call that function in your template:

```
<div class="card-deck" >
    {% if data|all_empty('supplier') %}
        <p>There is no data</p>
    {% else %}
        {% for sched in data %}
            {% if sched.supplier and sched.supplier.company %}
                <div class="row pl-3 ml-1">
                    <p>{{ sched.supplier.company }}</p>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I appreciate your help.  I am not so familiar with this so I am looking into it.